# AngularJS Menus in Ionic Framework using Translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have added the Angular NG Translate to my app, however when it comes to trying to translate the side menu items I cannot find a way to do this. Basically using the Angular translate requires you to use the expressions {{'TEXT1' | translate }}
but my sidemenu in app.component.ts is already using the {} I have tried to use expressions in expressions and it has not worked, or maybe I didn't do it correctly.

Here is my sidemene in app.component.ts

```
appPages: PageInterface[] = [
  { title: 'PageA', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageAPage },
  { title: 'PageB', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageBPage },
  { title: 'PageC', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageCPage },
  { title: 'PageD', component: TabsPage, tabComponent: PageDPage }

];
```

and the the way to translate each of the menu names (PageA for e.g) is by changing them to:

```
{{'PageA' | translate }}
```

As you can see, if I add extra expressions within an expression, it no longer works. Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [translate service](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service) to translate the strings before you initialize this `PageInterface[]` variable

Comment: JLewkovich thanks for this. Excuse me of my limited knowledge of AngularJs, but how exactly would I achieve this? How would I translate the strings before?

Comment: Instead of setting title directly to `PageA`, `PageB`, etc. You have temporary variables somewhere earlier in the controller where you perform the translation, then use this new variable in your `appPages` block, something like `title: translatedPageA` (notice there's no single quotes because it's a variable name, kind of like `TabsPage` or `PageAPage`)

Comment: I have set variable var translatedPageA = {{'HOME' | translate }}; just above the appPages: PageInterface[] but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue in giving the translation key from my json file in app.component.ts and translate it with the standard expression in app.html. So instead of `{{p.title}}` the output for the menu entry in app.html should be `{{p.title|translate}}`. When you use a tabs navigation you have to modify the code slightly (I use a sidemenu).

app.component.ts:

```
appPages: PageInterface[] = [
  { title: 'PAGE_A_TITLE', component: Page1 },
  { title: 'PAGE_B_TITLE', component: Page2 },
  { title: 'PAGE_C_TITLE', component: Page3 },
  { title: 'PAGE_D_TITLE', component: Page4 }
];
```

en.json:

```
{
    "PAGE_A_TITLE": "This is page one",
    "PAGE_B_TITLE": "Title for page two",
    "PAGE_C_TITLE": "And one more",
    "PAGE_D_TITLE": "Page 4"
}
```

app.html:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
            {{p.title|translate}}
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I used :) I should have come back here to answer my own question, but thanks for your response and getting back. It was my sidemenu that needed adjusting.